# Redirect multiple files using .htaccess

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects

I have a lot of files with a lot of sub directories which I moved one folder up, so, say, instead of `example.com/cdn/folder/folder/file.html`, it now looks like this `example.com/folder/folder/file.html`.

My problem lies in SEO, I have a lot of back links which point to files which used to be in the old directory structure, and everyone who tries to access these files via those links will get a 404.

Now, I know that I can resolve the problem by adding a simple line of code in *.htaccess*, so I have read quite a number of tutorials on the Internet which explain how to redirect files from one place to another using wildcards and `RedirectMatch` techniques. I have found [a site](http://alvinalexander.com/web/apache-redirectmatch-examples-wildcard-301) which explains how to do it, but I can't seem to get it working. I don't know what my problem is.

This is what I have come up with so far:

`RedirectMatch 301 /cdn/folder/folder/(.*)/(.*) http://example.com/folder/folder/$1/$2`

This, however, does not do what I want it to do. Say, if someone accesses a file via `example.com/cdn/folder/folder/file.html`, they will get a 404. The code above does not resolve the problem. But, it does what I want it to do only for `example.com/cdn/folder`. Someone trying to access the subdirectory of `/cdn` will be redirected to `/folder`.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you don't need to worry about how many folders are nested, just whether the requested URL is contained in the `/cdn` folder? If it is then remove it...

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cdn/(.*) /$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it was an easy fix. I guess I was overcomplicating things as usual...